# Can anyone tell me what literary device defines the following poem?

Tags: poetry

Can anyone tell me what literary device defines the following poem? I need to categorize this poem.

COVID-19 You will Never Own My Morale

By Adrian D'Costa

COVID-19. You, despicable virus.

Coronavirus. You wretched soul snatcher.

You will never own my high spirit.

You will never own my high morale.

I am standing on this

ground with my head held high.

I will leave this world

as an upright soul.

With my spinal cord straightened

looking at the sky.

You will never own me.

You will never persuade me

to believe I am an empty void

mirror of myself.

In my own world.

You will never going to

dissuade me to realize

this is the end of the Human Element.

I despise you.

For your vilified vile and for your venomous poison.

You are completely devoid of

the yearning for the entity called Love.

You could flatten me down on this land

of lowest probabilities.

But you will never own my high morale

to find a cure.

To help a broken solitude soul.

And this is the Humanity’s call

that I accept.

Comment: What do you mean by strongest? That is a relative, opinion-based question. Maybe take the [tour](https://writing.stackexchange.com/tour) and see [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). It is really hard to answer these sort of questions and it may be off topic.

Comment: @ArtickokeAndAnchovyPizza What literary device defines this poem?

Comment: Anything such as caesura, enjambement and any other poetical device could be said to "define this poem". There is no objective answer, in my opinion, .butit may be useful to look at  [English Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/) and see if this question is on topic.

Comment: I just realised: unless you yourself are Adrian d'Costa, this probably falls foul of our rule forbidding questions about existing works of literature. The purpose of this site is to help people with their *own* writing, not analyse other people's.